# iPad и Google Colab = нет возможности Cmd/Ctrl + C

Tags: python, apple, ipad

Есть iPad Air. Есть Magic Keyboard. Есть Google Colab. Но нет возможности копировать текст.

- Cmd + V - работает
- Cmd + C - нет.

Что нужно сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

На сайте онлайн питона всё работает, в колабе нет. Зашёл с ноута - всё норм, копипаста тоже работает.